# WP7 Mango ResouceDictionary MergedDictionaries

Tags: windows-phone-7, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

i am having problem with ResourceDictionary in WP7 Mango.

Most of what I could find on the internet is as simple as this:

1) Xaml file with body:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
 <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle1" TargetType="TextBlock">
 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
 <Setter  Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
 <Setter  Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

2) Add to App.xaml following:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml"/>
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
```

Not sure why it's not working. When doing it like this, I get exception:

The type 'ResourceDictionary' is inside a ResourceDictionary and does not have a key.

When I add ked to second xaml line in step 2, then it runs, but crashes with unspecified error.It looks like it does not add resouces from MyResources.xaml file.

Could someone point a solution here?

Comment: Firstly, ensure that the file "MyResources.xaml" exists and its "Build Action" is set to "Resource"

Comment: I dont think resource is needed as a Build Action since I got it just running on Page built action

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a key for the ResourceDictionary in App.xaml.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="keyname">
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml"/>
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: As I wrote in my question text, i tried adding with not a good outcome

Comment: I just realised that your Source does not have the corect format. It should be `Source="/{projectname};component/MyResource.xaml"`. More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.source%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I have Xaml inside the project, it is sufficient to call it as I did ( I got it running, but for some reason my answer is not published here )

Answer (score 1):

Actually figured it out.

I was trying to get it working without the key in  and found out that the styles that i left in App.xaml were making the problem. So all the remaining styling left in App.xaml i had to move inside  even though they were unique.

```
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>

   my remaining styles with key & target type are here now

   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml"/>
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

EDIT:

Few more important details that might save someone's time and took me a long time to figure those out:
1) As also MSDN recommends, you should not put Key inside ResourceDictionary

2) Styles inside referenced Xaml should all contain Key ( or Name )

3) Rest of the styles need to be placed as explained above

4) In following code, if you redefine a base style that some other styles are based on, changes will be not reflected until you redefine inherited styles too in MyResources2.xaml ( alternatively replace base style in MyResources.xaml with style in MyResources2.xaml )

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml"/>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources2.xaml"/>             
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

5) ResourceDictionaries in MergedDictionaries function as LIFO